# "You have already activated" message even when using bundle exec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm, capistrano, bundler

I am installing gems in my Gemfile in shared path as Capistrano does by default, and when I run:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get:

```
You have already activated rake 0.9.2.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.0.4. Using bundle exec may solve this.
```

See that:

```
cat Gemfile.lock | grep rake
```

returns:

```
  rake (>= 0.8.7)
rake (10.0.4)
```

This is my `gem environment` output:

```
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 448) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/bitnami/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/bitnami/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/bitnami/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gemhome" => "/home/bitnami/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/"
     - "gempath" => ["/home/bitnami/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

## Update

```
which -a rake
/opt/bitnami/rvm/bin/rake
/opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/rake
```

## Update 2

I tried giving full path to rake, but same problem

## Update 3

After reinstalling RVM

```
  * WARNING: Found gemhome in /home/bitnami/.gemrc, please remove it, as it will break rubygems in RVM.
  * WARNING: Found gempath in /home/bitnami/.gemrc, please remove it, as it will break rubygems in RVM.
    If it is intended or a mistake 'export rvm_ignore_gemrc_issues=1' to avoid this warning.
```

What should I do now? I added gem_home there because I want my gems to be installed in my desired directory, not sure if this is the right way.

Comment: can you paste the output of "gem list rake" ? when I am having this problem I used to uninstall that rake version. i.e. in your case gem uninstall rake -v 0.9.2.2.

Comment: gem does not detect 0.9.2.2 just gems installed at gem_home. so, say I have rake 10 in gem_home, gem list print rake 10, but not (0.9, 10)

Comment: It seems that you are using bitnami. I am assuming its path problem or multiple installation of RVM because of bitnami. I think you should go through documentation of Bitnami for RVM. http://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Ruby_on_Rails/RVM#Tweaking_RVM. I have just faced Bitnami environment for one project and faced problem for Apache (: May be this would help you

Answer (score 1):

you need to follow the instructions, if the installer tells there are incompatible settings then you need to clear them, usually this should do just fine:

```
rm -f ~/.gemrc
```

a common solution to this is also disabling docs (not needed on server and not many users use them locally anyway):

```
echo 'gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc' > ~/.gemrc
```

Both will get rid of the old `~/.gemrc` which was forcing `gemhome` / `gempath` - this is required as this variables are controled with RVM via environment variables `GEM_HOME` / `GEM_PATH`.

After `~/.gemrc` is fixed run:

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default --install
```

it will make sure ruby is installed, set as default and properly loaded into current environment.

Comment: I don't have any ruby version installed, but after reinstalling RVM ...see update

Comment: Actually `rvm current` returns `system`, and `ruby -v ` returns `1.9.3...` I don't feel right to install a new Ruby, the AMI already has one, I think that AMI is difficult to handle.

Comment: ok please explain what for do you need RVM if you do not use it to install rubies?

Comment: hmm, Actually is installed by default in the AMI I use.